# How to group the similar json data-react native

Tags: json, react-native

In my react native app I am fetching the data from sever which is in JSON format and I am displaying it in listview. I want to group similar JSON  and display inside Popup and listrow will display only one flight and upon click on listrow popup will be open which will display all the similar flights at same price.

Like I want to display similar flights from same airline with same price but having different time slots..